# Notification when new data is inserted into table

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on an e-commerce website, Currently got stuck at the point where I have a contact form where customers fill in their details and send it and data will be stored into the table called messages.

Now I have a page messages page fetching all the messages from database where site admin can see the messages
I want to show notification on messages  li that they got a new message

```
<li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a></li>
```

How do I do that?

here is all code

```
     $presults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY DATE DESC"); 

    <h2 class="text-center">Messages</h2>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<hr>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
     <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Subject</th>
          <th>Date Received</th>
          <th>message</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <?php 
               while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($presults)) : ?>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" href="messages.php?delete=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
               </td>
               <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $product['email']; ?> </td>
               <td><?php echo $product['subject']; ?> </td>
               <td><?php echo $product['date']; ?> </td>
               <td><?php echo $product['message']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
     </tbody
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the page where "LI" tag is exit make sql query to check the database to see if there are any new meesages or not.

if there are no new messages do nothing .... if there apply any style for the LI tag ( for example make it bold or red colored )

```
if( true ){
echo '<li style="colore:#ff0000">messages</li>';
}else{
echo '<li>messages</li>';
}
```